# Получить постоянную ссылку из js фильтрации

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сайт https://inpsycho.ru/lecture_hall , при нажатии по кнопке "Онлайн" происходит фильтрация. Можно ли как-то узнать название параметра, чтобы иметь возможность переходить на страницу с уже отфильтрованными значениями? К примеру:  [https://inpsycho.ru/lecture_hall?filter=Онлайн](https://inpsycho.ru/lecture_hall?filter=%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD)

Answer (score 2):

Обычным `GET` запросом эти данные не получить, однако путем небольших эксперементов я выяснил что `POST` запрос может вернуть записи в статусе `online`:

```js
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("format", "Онлайн");
formdata.append("route", "/lecture_hall");
formdata.append("limit", "5");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.inpsycho.ru/api/get-content", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

В Postman это будет выглядеть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для полной ясности откуда и почему такие параметры приведу скрин параметров оригинального POST запроса делаемого сайтом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Супер! А нельзя никак исходя из этих данных получить прямую ссылку на отфильтрованные значения? Например https://inpsycho.ru/lecture_hall?format=Онлайн не срабатывает

Comment: то что пишется через адресную строку - это `GET` запрос, и он не обрабатывается сервером. Причина не в силе нашего желания, а в желании `бекэнд разработчика`, поэтому нельзя.